# each_with_index not working for an array rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

When `each_with_index` is used along with an `array` of `active records` returned from a query and when i call the `attributes` of the **model**. it says `undefined method`, for the `attribute`

**Controller**

```
@user_contact_query=Usercontact.select("*")
@available_contacts_array=Array.new
@user_contact_query.each do |variable|
  @user_query=User.find( :all,:conditions => ["id = ?",variable.relator_id])
  @available_contacts_array.push(@user_query)  
end
```

**View**

```
<% @available_contacts_array.each_with_index do |variable, index| %>
  <%= variable.email %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

First off please post your full error message. Although Without seeing the error I can tell with certainty that the issue is caused by you calling a method on a nil object i.e you think a value exists where it actually does not.

Besides that you really really should take more care of your code. The code you have right now is just plain horrible. This is an equivalent of your code:

```
@available = []

UserContact.find_each do |contact|
  @available << User.find(contact.relator_id)
end
```

An alternative is to use #inject

```
@available = UserContact.all.inject([]) do |list, contact|
  list << User.find(contact.relator_id)
  list
end
```

And the best solution would be to actually use ActiveRecord assocations here.

P.S your code does not make much sense anyhow. Why would you put users contacts and users both into that list?

Comment: Sorry ,i was trying out something and posted it here , without undo ing changes

Answer (score 1):

Well, step by step, since this is rather bad code:

```
@user_contact_query = Usercontact.select("*")
```

the select part here is a bit strange, I would have used `.all`. Otherwise no problem here.

```
@available_contacts_array = Array.new
```

since in the next line you assign an array anyway there is no need to 'initialize' this variable here, you could just omit that line. (Most Ruby programmers would use `[]` to initialize an empty array in most cases)

```
@available_contacts_array = @user_contact_query.to_a
```

Assuming that we get some records back from the query we now should have an array with user contact objects. Again a simple `.all` would have had a similar effect as far as I understand what's going on. But assuming that Usercontact has `email` this is fine and what you expect it to be.

```
@user_contact_query.each do |variable|
  @user_query = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id = ?", variable.relator_id])
  @available_contacts_array.push(@user_query)  
end
```

Now if I get this right what you do is you go through all Usercontacts you found, find every User related to it (possibly more than one) and then attach the result at the end of the array of Usercontacts. As a result you have a mix of Users and Usercontacts in that array. (Which still would work in your view if both have email, since thanks to duck typing Ruby would not care. But most likely one of both is missing `email`). Also if more than one User is found then an array of users is pushed. And an array for sure has no `email`.

Ok, with your edit it becomes simple. When you use `:all` with `find` then what you get is not a record but an array of records (even if there us only one.). You can just do:

```
User.find(variable.relator_id)
```

which will then find a single record and push that in the array. Which I guess is what you expect it to do.

There would be better ways in Rails to do this but this would require the models to be defined properly what your use of `relator_id` makes look unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i made a mistake i edited the question

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you do just?

**controller's helper**:

```
@array = Usercontact.select( "*" ).map do| variable |
   User.find( :all,:conditions => [ "id = ?",variable.relator_id ])
end
```

**view's helper**:

```
@array.each.with_index do| variable, index |
   # ...
end
```

**General note**: you'be used in the `@available_contacts_array` variable mixed types, probably this lead to the error, please don't do in such matter.

Comment: downvoter which is argues?

Comment: .select("*") is pointless, should use User.find(id) instead of User.find(:all, :conditions ...) and your each_with_index call contains a typo, i.e it does not work. I wont even start on the formatting...

Comment: @TanelSuurhans which is the typo? and I don't know what exactly author wished to say with `select("*")`. So I just copied the code.

Comment: Sorry, not a typo, my bad. It's just a very underused and foreign looking way of doing looping with indexes. each_with_index vs each.with_index

Comment: @TanelSuurhans no it just common way to use indexing, and more proper.

Comment: I disagree, but that is my own subjective view and I won't argue about it here on SO.

Comment: @TanelSuurhans yes, but if you are downvoter, what the problem with answer?